# submit query to return multiple columns based off of the date?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that lists service calls for employees. i have a view set up to view the sum of the invoices in the table.

```
Select EmployeeID, SUM(InvoiceAmount) as "Total $ Amount Of Calls For January"
From Calls
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2013/01/01' AND '2013/01/31'
Group by EmployeeID
```

this works great but i have to do it twelve times to view each month and this seems a bit redundant. i would like to be able to use a sub query to display EmployeeID and then list each month with totals underneath.

```
EmployeeID   JAN   FEB   MAR   APR ...
john         444   555   342   654
jim          945   675   232   465
```

ive tried a bunch of things and cant get even close...i need something like this, but that works...

```
SELECT   
EmployeeID, 

(SELECT SUM(InvoiceAmount) FROM Orders WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2013/01/01' AND '2013/01/31') AS JAN,

(SELECT SUM(InvoiceAmount) FROM Orders WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2013/02/01' AND '2013/02/28') AS FEB,

(SELECT SUM(InvoiceAmount) FROM Orders WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2013/03/01' AND '2013/03/31') AS MAR,

FROM Calls
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, 
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN strftime('%m', Date) = '01'
                THEN InvoiceAmount
            ELSE 0
        END) AS 'Jan',
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN strftime('%m', Date) = '02'
                THEN InvoiceAmount
            ELSE 0
        END) AS 'Feb',
    ...
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN strftime('%m', Date) = '12'
                THEN InvoiceAmount
            ELSE 0
        END) AS 'Dec'
FROM Calls
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

This works well if you're looking at a particular year.

### [See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c4bc7/1)

Comment: im still very new to databse syntax, however im using sqlite not mysql, my SQL manager says that "if" is an improper function. not sure if that would make a difference?

Comment: this script finally returned but the columns are blank. i have the date format as YYYY/MM/DD. which is the default for sqlite, however strftime in php you can define the format of the date. does this need to be done here?

Comment: @derek Hopefully I've made the last update. I've created [a new fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c4bc7/1) using this query.

Comment: thank you, the previous one probably would have worked as well...i was racking my brain trying to figure out if the date format could be the reason...my dates are inserted into the table as 2013/01/01 not 2013-01-01. guess i learned something new. thank you again for your time. i think my very basic knowledge of sql was irritating the other person as they removed their answer.

Comment: @derek No, this not right. I just removed it because it seems like I am irritating someone else who dwonvoted it with my answers. And I found that this answer is more helpful and it said what I was trying to say and he posted it first. Thats why I deleted it. Sorry for that.

Comment: ok, well thank you both. the one posted above works perfectly